# How do I avoid reserved words in a Query's range?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets query below that returns an error due to the usage of the reserved word "BY."

I have tried back quotes and backquotes with parentheses to escape the "BY" but I am unsure of the syntax to escape both the "$B4:BY" and the "COMUMN(BY3)."

```
=sumproduct(query($B4:BY,"select " & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(BY3),4), "1", "") & " where B<>'Hide'"))
```

I am positive my formula works because it works in adjacent columns BX and BZ. However in column BY it returns the following `#VALUE` error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "by" "BY "" at line 1, column 8. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null" ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second" ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... "(" ... "*" ... "-" ...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(B4:BY, "select `BY` where not B = 'Hide'", 0))
```

**BY** column should be escaped by single backquotes:

## ``` `` ```

Comment: Using only `BY` in my formula does not work. I must refer to BY3 to pass along another variable. I am unable to determine the syntax for referring to an escaped "BY3." Thank you.

Comment: BY needs to be escaped only in query selection